# flutter go_router how to know the navigation type

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

We've got a scenario where we're trying to intercept the user's use of the back button in the browser, however, when using the onExit of the GoRoute it seems to trigger when push and go's also take place.

Is there a way of finding the navigation action that has taken place?